# LWJGL glCreateBuffers causing problems

Tags: java, opengl, runtime-error, lwjgl

So I'm new to OpenGL, and I've been following several tutorials on how to draw a simple triangle. I don't use shaders here, even though I know how to use them. The tutorials say to create a buffer using `glCreateBuffers`, but everything I change in the code doesn't prevent the error. I've been following the OpenGL Programming Guide, and watched several YouTube videos on the topic. I've also updated to the most recent NVIDIA drivers for my graphics card. What did I do wrong?

The error, which also contains all of the hardware specifications:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffa120235d, pid=4592, tid=0x00000000000035a8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0x235d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000032a9000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=13736, stack(0x0000000003160000,0x0000000003260000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000830

Registers:
RAX=0x000000005619ed50, RBX=0x000000001a523d28, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x000000001daa7d5c
RSP=0x000000000325f4f8, RBP=0x000000000325f580, RSI=0x0000000000000048, RDI=0x0000000003507e70
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x000000001daa7d5c, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000055c2b4a0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001a523d28, R14=0x000000000325f5b0, R15=0x00000000032a9000
RIP=0x00007fffa120235d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000325f4f8)
0x000000000325f4f8:   0000000003517f54 0000000003507e70
0x000000000325f508:   0000000003517cbd 00000000032a9000
0x000000000325f518:   000000001a523d28 0000000000000048
0x000000000325f528:   00000000032a9000 000000000325f628
0x000000000325f538:   0000000003517c82 000000000325f540
0x000000000325f548:   000000001a523d28 000000000325f5b0
0x000000000325f558:   000000001a539f98 0000000000000000
0x000000000325f568:   000000001a523d28 0000000000000000
0x000000000325f578:   000000000325f5a0 000000000325f5f8
0x000000000325f588:   000000000350835d 00000007813fb2d8
0x000000000325f598:   00000000035119d8 000000001daa7d5c
0x000000000325f5a8:   0000000781481140 0000000000000001
0x000000000325f5b8:   000000000325f5b8 000000001a523e7c
0x000000000325f5c8:   000000000325f628 000000001a539f98
0x000000000325f5d8:   0000000000000000 000000001a523ee0
0x000000000325f5e8:   000000000325f5a0 000000000325f630 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fffa120235d)
0x00007fffa120233d:   ff a2 28 17 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fffa120234d:   cc cc cc 48 8b 01 49 8b d1 41 8b c8 4c 8b 50 18
0x00007fffa120235d:   49 ff a2 30 08 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00007fffa120236d:   cc cc cc 40 53 48 8b 01 41 8b d8 4c 8b 44 24 30 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000005619ed50 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x000000001a523d30} 'nglCreateBuffers' '(IJ)V' in 'org/lwjgl/opengl/GL45'
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000001daa7d5c is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000325f4f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000032a9000
RBP=0x000000000325f580 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000032a9000
RSI=0x0000000000000048 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000003507e70 is at code_begin+1040 in an Interpreter codelet
invoke return entry points  [0x0000000003507a60, 0x0000000003508440]  2528 bytes
R8 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000001daa7d5c is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000055c2b4a0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000000001a523d30} 'nglCreateBuffers' '(IJ)V' in 'org/lwjgl/opengl/GL45'
R14=0x000000000325f5b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000032a9000
R15=0x00000000032a9000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000003160000,0x0000000003260000],  sp=0x000000000325f4f8,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0x235d]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL45.nglCreateBuffers(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL45.glCreateBuffers()I+20
j  com.meti.HelloTriangle.init()V+169
j  com.meti.HelloTriangle.run()V+1
j  com.meti.HelloTriangle.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001cbaf000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15408, stack(0x000000001d6a0000,0x000000001d7a0000)]
  0x000000001cbb6800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4928, stack(0x000000001d5a0000,0x000000001d6a0000)]
  0x000000001cbae000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15648, stack(0x000000001d4a0000,0x000000001d5a0000)]
  0x000000001cbb2800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3528, stack(0x000000001d3a0000,0x000000001d4a0000)]
  0x000000001cbad800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2988, stack(0x000000001d2a0000,0x000000001d3a0000)]
  0x000000001caf6000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10828, stack(0x000000001d1a0000,0x000000001d2a0000)]
  0x000000001c8e4800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15864, stack(0x000000001d0a0000,0x000000001d1a0000)]
  0x000000001c8e3000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13440, stack(0x000000001cfa0000,0x000000001d0a0000)]
  0x000000001a9e4000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15624, stack(0x000000001ccb0000,0x000000001cdb0000)]
  0x000000000339e000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13760, stack(0x000000001c7b0000,0x000000001c8b0000)]
=>0x00000000032a9000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=13736, stack(0x0000000003160000,0x0000000003260000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001a9d9000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001c6b0000,0x000000001c7b0000] [id=13368]
  0x000000001cbc0000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001dfa0000,0x000000001e0a0000] [id=13180]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 57344K, used 11847K [0x0000000780900000, 0x0000000784900000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 49152K, 24% used [0x0000000780900000,0x0000000781491f48,0x0000000783900000)
  from space 8192K, 0% used [0x0000000784100000,0x0000000784100000,0x0000000784900000)
  to   space 8192K, 0% used [0x0000000783900000,0x0000000783900000,0x0000000784100000)
 ParOldGen       total 131072K, used 0K [0x0000000701a00000, 0x0000000709a00000, 0x0000000780900000)
  object space 131072K, 0% used [0x0000000701a00000,0x0000000701a00000,0x0000000709a00000)
 Metaspace       used 6034K, capacity 6220K, committed 6400K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 655K, capacity 738K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000128c0000,0x0000000012ec0000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000f0b3000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005621a6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013ac0000, 0x0000000016a58000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000016a58000, 0x00000000199f0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001300000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2341Kb max_used=2353Kb free=243418Kb
 bounds [0x0000000003500000, 0x0000000003770000, 0x0000000012500000]
 total_blobs=1191 nmethods=469 adapters=635
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.540 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800  465       3       java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream::read (32 bytes)
Event: 0.540 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800 nmethod 465 0x0000000003745dd0 code [0x0000000003745f60, 0x00000000037463d8]
Event: 0.541 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800  466       3       java.util.WeakHashMap::remove (133 bytes)
Event: 0.542 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800 nmethod 466 0x0000000003746590 code [0x0000000003746780, 0x0000000003747268]
Event: 0.545 Thread 0x000000001cbad800 nmethod 463 0x000000000374a6d0 code [0x000000000374a820, 0x000000000374ac38]
Event: 0.545 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800  467       3       sun.misc.JarIndex::get (49 bytes)
Event: 0.545 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800 nmethod 467 0x0000000003749950 code [0x0000000003749b20, 0x000000000374a398]
Event: 0.546 Thread 0x000000001cbae000  468       4       java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
Event: 0.546 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800  469       3       java.net.URL::toString (5 bytes)
Event: 0.546 Thread 0x000000001cbb6800 nmethod 469 0x0000000003749410 code [0x0000000003749580, 0x0000000003749868]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 0.270 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000367a394 method=java.lang.String.indexOf([CII[CIII)I @ 134

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.039 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x0000000780907fa8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\��1����?
Event: 0.234 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': java.lang.Object.lambda$static$0(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Boolean;> (0x0000000780f3d758) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.:%�l��?
Event: 0.248 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x0000000780fbfba0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.249 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x0000000780fcda48) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.296 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007811bcef8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.296 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007811bd108) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.296 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007811c11d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.296 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007811c13e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.543 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x0000000781462538) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.544 Thread 0x00000000032a9000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x0000000781463f38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.544 loading class java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException
Event: 0.544 loading class java/nio/file/FileSystemException
Event: 0.544 loading class java/nio/file/FileSystemException done
Event: 0.544 loading class java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException done
Event: 0.544 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$1
Event: 0.544 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$1 done
Event: 0.545 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$SharedLibraryGL
Event: 0.545 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$SharedLibraryGL done
Event: 0.545 loading class org/lwjgl/system/SharedLibrary$Delegate
Event: 0.545 loading class org/lwjgl/system/SharedLibrary$Delegate done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff63a440000 - 0x00007ff63a477000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe
0x00007fffbc000000 - 0x00007fffbc1db000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fffbb630000 - 0x00007fffbb6de000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fffb86c0000 - 0x00007fffb8909000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007fffbabe0000 - 0x00007fffbac81000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007fffbbf60000 - 0x00007fffbbffd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007fffbb6e0000 - 0x00007fffbb739000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007fffbb8a0000 - 0x00007fffbb9c5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fffbb750000 - 0x00007fffbb89a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007fffb8970000 - 0x00007fffb898e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007fffbaa60000 - 0x00007fffbaa87000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fffb93d0000 - 0x00007fffb9558000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007fffb8620000 - 0x00007fffb86ba000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007fffb8520000 - 0x00007fffb8616000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007fffa8480000 - 0x00007fffa86e7000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.483_none_26002d27e7c744a2\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007fffbba70000 - 0x00007fffbbd69000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007fffb8990000 - 0x00007fffb89fa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007fffbbd90000 - 0x00007fffbbdbd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00000000562a0000 - 0x0000000056372000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000055a00000 - 0x000000005629a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fffbb9d0000 - 0x00007fffbb9d8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fffb46f0000 - 0x00007fffb46f9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007fffb5410000 - 0x00007fffb5433000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fffbb360000 - 0x00007fffbb3cc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fffabe10000 - 0x00007fffabe3b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007fffad5f0000 - 0x00007fffad5fa000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007fffb8a00000 - 0x00007fffb8a49000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000057380000 - 0x000000005738f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000057350000 - 0x0000000057379000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000057320000 - 0x0000000057343000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x0000000057300000 - 0x0000000057316000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007fffb9620000 - 0x00007fffbaa56000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007fffbaa90000 - 0x00007fffbab3a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007fffb8a50000 - 0x00007fffb9143000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007fffbb190000 - 0x00007fffbb1e1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007fffb8490000 - 0x00007fffb84a1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007fffb84b0000 - 0x00007fffb84fc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007fffb8470000 - 0x00007fffb8485000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007fffabef0000 - 0x00007fffabf0a000     C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-1\172.3968.16\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00000000559e0000 - 0x00000000559fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007fffb7d20000 - 0x00007fffb7d7c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00000000559c0000 - 0x00000000559d1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007fffa87b0000 - 0x00007fffa8807000     C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglmathm\3.1.2-build-29\lwjgl.dll
0x00007fffa8770000 - 0x00007fffa87ac000     C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglmathm\3.1.2-build-29\jemalloc.dll
0x00007fffa5e30000 - 0x00007fffa5e6d000     C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglmathm\3.1.2-build-29\glfw.dll
0x00007fffb6ce0000 - 0x00007fffb6d75000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007fffa4f50000 - 0x00007fffa4f92000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dinput8.dll
0x00007fffb4630000 - 0x00007fffb463e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput1_4.dll
0x00007fffb6f90000 - 0x00007fffb6fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007fffad130000 - 0x00007fffad15a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007fffbb1f0000 - 0x00007fffbb356000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007fffbb0d0000 - 0x00007fffbb190000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007fffaccf0000 - 0x00007fffacd18000     c:\program files\nvidia corporation\nvstreamsrv\nvinject.dll
0x00007fffb7320000 - 0x00007fffb732d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
0x00007fffbac90000 - 0x00007fffbb0cb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.DLL
0x00007fffb8910000 - 0x00007fffb8966000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007fffb8500000 - 0x00007fffb8511000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007fffb9200000 - 0x00007fffb93c9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007fffa1290000 - 0x00007fffa13b1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\opengl32.dll
0x00007fffad870000 - 0x00007fffad89c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007fff66980000 - 0x00007fff676ca000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_463164d40c3d26ce\ig9icd64.dll
0x00007fffb48f0000 - 0x00007fffb4903000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007fffa3730000 - 0x00007fffa488d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_463164d40c3d26ce\igc64.dll
0x00007fffaf3b0000 - 0x00007fffaf432000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
0x00007fffb5ee0000 - 0x00007fffb5fc3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00007fffa76a0000 - 0x00007fffa7972000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00007fffb1f30000 - 0x00007fffb1f45000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
0x00007fffb7670000 - 0x00007fffb76a1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007fffb52d0000 - 0x00007fffb5409000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007fffa1200000 - 0x00007fffa125c000     C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjglmathm\3.1.2-build-29\lwjgl_opengl.dll
0x00007fffb42c0000 - 0x00007fffb4469000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-1\172.3968.16\lib\idea_rt.jar=53725:C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-1\172.3968.16\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.meti.HelloTriangle
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\out\production\LwjglProjects;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl-javadoc.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl-sources.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl-natives-linux.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl-natives-macos.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl\lwjgl-natives-windows.jar;C:\Meticuli\Projects\LwjglProjects\libraries\lwjgl-3.1.2\lwjgl-assimp\lwjgl-assimp.jar;
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\mathm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME=mathm
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.296)

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 94 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 12476176k(7696764k free), swap 13296400k(7350476k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_101-b13), built on Jun 22 2016 01:21:29 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sat Sep 16 16:46:48 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I do hate working with native code in Java, albeit knowing OpenGL is a good skill to have.

Here is the source code:

```
package com.meti;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBindBuffer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glBindVertexArray;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL45.glCreateBuffers;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL45.glNamedBufferStorage;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

/**
 * @author SirMathhman
 * @version 0.0.0
 * @since 9/8/2017
 */
public class HelloTriangle {
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private long window;
    private int vaoID;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloTriangle().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        init();
        loop();
    }

    private void init() {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        if (!glfwInit()) {
            System.out.println("GLFW failed to initialize");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "HelloWindow", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            System.out.println("GLFW failed to create window");
            glfwTerminate();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        float[] vertices = {
                -0.9f, -0.9f,
                0.85f, -0.9f,
                -0.9f, 0.85f,
                0.9f, -0.85f,
                0.9f, 0.9f,
                -0.85f, 0.9f
        };

        int buffer = glCreateBuffers();
        glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, vertices, vertices.length);

        vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    private void loop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        glfwTerminate();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

PS: Is there also a way to return a more detailed error thrown by the driver by LWJGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glCreateBuffers` and `glNamedBufferStorage` are OpenGL 4.5 commands. But you are requesting 3.3 (the `glfwWindowHint` commands).

If you want to stick to 3.3 version, try creating a buffer with `glGenBuffers`

Comment: Lol, forgot to add that there.